# ORACLE - comment all columns of all tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanna comment all columns of all tables where the column have Foreing key with one especific table.

I know comment one by one, but they are many fields

Comment: so write a script.  There is no "alter many comments" command.

Comment: So use dynamic SQL, looping over the affected columns. Can't really be more specific with so little information.

Comment: Unless you want the same comment each time, do it manually.  It's a one time job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
'COMMENT ON COLUMN ' as command1,
SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.OWNER,
'.' as command2,
SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME,
'.' as command3,
SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME,
' is ''@Enumeration=boleano' as coment_to_add,
SYS.ALL_COL_COMMENTS.COMMENTS,
''';' as command5
FROM
SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
INNER JOIN SYS.ALL_COL_COMMENTS ON SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME = SYS.ALL_COL_COMMENTS.COLUMN_NAME AND SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = SYS.ALL_COL_COMMENTS.TABLE_NAME AND SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.OWNER = SYS.ALL_COL_COMMENTS.OWNER
WHERE
SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.OWNER LIKE '$MY_OWNER'
```

The result exported to txt file is the script;